# Angular 7 error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to learn angular by following the [**official tutorial**](https://angular.io/tutorial/) but when following steps for `hero component` and `hero detail component`, it raises an error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

The `hero.component.html`:

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- 
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail> -->


<app-heroes></app-heroes>
```

The `detail component`:

```
<div *ngIf="hero">

  <h2>{{hero.name}} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </label>
  </div>

</div>

<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

The `hero component`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];

  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroes = this.heroService.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

}
```

The `hero.detail component`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() hero: Hero;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

one thing to mention is that when `<app-heroes></app-heroes>` is commented, the list page is loaded without an error

[image: Error message screenshot]
any help is appreciated

Comment: In your example you render component inside yourself, so you never finish this operation and all time render another child component (if second part of block is `<app-hero-detail>`

Comment: If you are looking in console, there might be an error before the error that is mentioned in your question. Can you please check and update the same

Comment: @SachinGupta screenshot uploaded

Comment: Same error messages, if any feature module, are same in child and parent module.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1.This error occur when there is an infinite loop.
As you have mentioned that the page loads when **app-heroes** is commented, **this might be used as selector-name for more than one component** which is not allowed.
This can cause an infinite loop and fail to load components.

2. Try making below edits,

**hero.component.html**

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedhero"></app-hero-detail>
```

**hero.detail.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="hero">
  <h2>{{hero.name}} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hello . have checked and that doesnt seem to be the case . (question updated)

Comment: Can you please create an example to replicate your problem here
https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @AbdulAli `doesn't seem to help` then why was it marked as answer?

Comment: @CaptainPrinny It worked after eidting the answer :)

Answer (score 8):

This error occurred when I used a circular module import mistakenly on Angular 9.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ModuleTwo
  ],
 
})
export class ModuleOne {
}
```

and

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
    @NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ModuleOne
      ],
     
    })
    export class ModuleTwo {
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

In your example you render component inside yourself, so you never finish this operation and all time render another child component (if second part of block is

Update - more details:

If you write app with components, all components are hierarchical, so you can include the same component inside yourself only if you are sure, that this is limited amount of loop inside. In your code example you has unlimited nested components, because child component generate next child component inside yourself body. In result your browser display error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

hero.component.html

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- 
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail> -->


<app-heroes></app-heroes>
```

app-hero-details.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="hero">

  <h2>{{hero.name}} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </label>
  </div>

</div>

// you should comment line below
// <app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. can you kindly explain a bit as am completely new to angular and the components' hierarchy

Comment: Great answer... A good example would be naming a component "header", which would conflict with a header tag inside the component partial.

Answer (score 7):

I will add an answer that describes a different cause for this error when upgrading to angular 8 an existing application and using new routing features.

In my case, I added to each lazy loaded route the `data` object with `preload` set to `true || false` using the new syntax:

```
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule),
    data: { preload: true }
  },
```

However it took me a while to realize that I had left the `preloadingStrategy` set to `PreloadAllModules` in my `RouterModule` forRoot declaration:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(
    routes,
    {
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, <-- This is the cause
    })],
    ...
```

Removing preloadingStrategy from the module forRoot declaration and relying on the route data preload definitio fixes the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I was dealing with this error when my intellisense accidentally added the module name (instead of a specific component name) to the exports for the module:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FooComponent,
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [
    FooModule, // <== should be 'FooComponent'
    // ...
  ], 
})
export class FooModule {}
```

It definitely would be nice if the error was a little more descriptive though, as this tool me some time

Comment: Mine was similar in nature. AppModule was pulled into a child module which is imported inside of AppModule. In my case, Intellij did the damage.

Answer (score 4):

You have the `<app-hero-detail>` displayed inside the details HTML.

```
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

Please try removing this. A similar line is commented in the `hero.component.html`, you can uncomment that.

Answer (score 2):

A different cause for this error when upgrading to angular 8 an existing application and using new routing features in separate file.

In my case not importing the `featureRouterModule` to its particular `featureModule.ts` cause maximum stack exceed error.Since angular can't find its particular router file registered

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this error message when I created a module and I forget to add the RoutingModule.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  SuccessComponent,
  CheckoutComponent
],
  imports: [
    ShareModule,
    PaymentRoutingModule // Forget to add it.
  ]
})
export class PaymentModule { }
```

I have no idea why I got this error, but maybe another person can make the same mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Possible cases for this error which I found:

- 2 or more modules with the same name
- Wrong imports in your `app.module.ts` file
- Problem with compilation

Solution that you can try:

- for point 1, change the names and make them unique
- for point 2, make sure all imports are intended as per your use case for a module, do check for inter-dependency between modules
- for point 3, rare but happens if browser doesn't have enough memory to process, so try to restart your code editor, browser or your PC.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had a routing module export with the module export name, just needed to add "routing"to the name.

Answer (score 1):

This happened when I was subscribing to an observable more frequently than required. I was subscribing to the below observable on every Enter key press,

```
this.filteredOptions.subscribe((res) => this.addSelectedContacts(event, res[keyManager.activeItemIndex]))
```

This was obviously not required, I had to limit the observable to only get the first emission by adding pipe(**take(1)**) as,

```
this.filteredOptions.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((res) => this.addSelectedContacts(event, res[keyManager.activeItemIndex]))
```

You might also use the **swithMap** operator syntax to dismiss previous subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I named two modules similarly and didn't pay attention to which I imported.
If you import a module inside itself it will cause circular import till maximum call stack is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I solved an infinite loop ploblemma I was having after I removed a call from a service I was doing within the same service, but with different behavior.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Angular 12

I encounter this on a infinite loop which causes ui to change on every iteration.